# How to update this order status in mongodb ? here One order Id and products are in an array and inside poduct object it contain status

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60e1db6c8418dc720d9bf38b"),
    "products" : [
        {
            "pid" : ObjectId("60da10e21b35eb7e76a2a0d6"),
            "qty" : 1,
            "productname" : "Lives all product check",
            "pType" : "SHOE",
            "prize" : 44,
            "total" : 42,
            "status" : "Orderd",
            "orderDate" : "Sunday, July 4, 2021",
            "shipDate" : "",
            "expDelivery" : "Sunday, July 11, 2021",
            "DeliveredDate" : ""
        }
    ],
    "payment" : "cashonDelivery",
    "totalOfOrder" : 42,
    "placedDated" : "Sunday, July 4, 2021",
    "shippingCharg" : 120,
    "__v" : 0

}`
```

*how to change array of object value in mongodb
i need to change the status of my product with mongoose. id didn't anything to work with that

*

Answer (score 0):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/daKaNGE7W5E

Use [`$[<identifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)

> The filtered positional operator $[] identifies the array elements that match the arrayFilters conditions for an update operation

```
db.collection.update({},
  {  $set: { "products.$[p].status": "delivered" } },
  {  arrayFilters: [ { "p.pid": ObjectId("60da10e21b35eb7e76a2a0d6") } ]}
)
```

Comment: Order.updateOne( {_id:ObjectId(oid), products: { $elemMatch: {pid: ObjectId(productID)} } },{$set:{ 'products.$.status':st}},(err,result)=>{
               resolve(result)
            })

Comment: @Shuhaibzahir please explain ?